# MongoDB for Forex

Tags: mongodb, feed, forex

I was wondering, can MongoDB be used for storing Forex data which would be later presented on client applications as real time data with analisys in form of graphs? I will have different sources  with different feeds which can not be found from mainstream data providers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at these [papers](http://www.10gen.com/events/mongosf-2010) coming from the MongoSF convention. Particularly about the analytics. Be aware that the data storage is only one aspect of - in this case - a very complex system design.

Comment: Thanks for this link, but I am curious why did you give -1?

Comment: It wasn't me. If I gave -1 I would not bother answering and, by the way, I do not have enough score to vote down.

Comment: Oh, sorry. My position is that there are no stupid questions, just answers. Your answer is definitely NOT stupid one... :)

Comment: @DevetiPutnik: oh, there definitely ARE stupid questions. :-)

Comment: Just to top up with a pinch of phylosophy, stupid questions are very often obvious ones.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB can be used to store Forex data, the same all databases (that I can think of) will be able to. I think the big question is what do you want to get out of your data storage?

If you are after high performance, then NoSQL is certainly a good direction to go in, as they typically provide better speeds on large datasets when the table relationships get complex.

To be honest though, regardless of feeds - Forex data can be typically stored with a DateTime/High/Low/Open/Close/Currency/Interval right? I use SQL Server to do a very similar thing than what you described, and accessing the stored data is NOT the performance bottleneck. When you start trying to translate the data into the graphs and add indicators etc.. that's when the good design decisions pay off.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB can be used to store Forex data just like the rest of the data base systems. However, if one is after high performance NOSQL is a better option because it provides better speeds on large sets of data.

Comment: MongoDB is a NoSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

A little information on MongoDB and use with financial markets:
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-single-platform-all-financial-data-ahl

Arctic is a great open source datastore solution which uses MongoDB and Python:
http://www.slideshare.net/JamesBlackburn1/2015-pydata-highperformance-iot-and-financial-data-storage-with-python-and-mongodb